# Search in Dynamodb db

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm using Lambda, API-gateway & Dynamodb using python 3.6
I have a dynamodb table for order id:

- orderId (primary Key|String)
- orderStatus (String)
- orderCode (String)
- date (String)

OrderId is unique. 
Whenever I try to query by date I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      8,
      "lambda_handler",
      "\"date\":day"
    ]
```

My code:

```py
    import boto3
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Shops')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        day = event['day']
        resp = table.get_item(Key={
        "date":day
        })
        return resp['Item']
```

I want to write a query that takes one date as input and will return all orders on that day:

This was my input:

```
{
  "day": "191215"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible in DynamoDB. You always have to provide a primary key, whether you query or trying to [get a specific item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item).

Of course, you can [scan the table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) but as you are probably aware this is a very expensive operation.

You can always create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with `date` as it's primary key and query the index instead.